# Xeround Discontinuing - 2 weeks to find an alternative

Tags: mysql, xeround

Xeround have just informed me that they are discontinuing their public cloud offering and given us 2 weeks to migrate.  Our system went live less than 2 months ago and I am now in a panic.

Can anyone recommend an alternative that is likely to be easy to migrate to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and easy would be to migrate to Amazon RDS.  You'll lose some availability (15 minute downtime due to hardware failure vs. none with Xeround), but unless your database is exceptionally large, it should be a fairly painless migration.

Amazon RDS supports MySQL, and has options for read replicas and failover configurations that might mitigate the availability issue.

Comment: Thanks.  Looking at Amazon.  Database is small so may well be an option

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any experience with this type of service or Xeround, but [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=dbaas+providers+-%22xeround%22) search looks like it might return a few good options.

One of the options that I found is [Cloudant](http://www.cloudant.com).

Comment: One of my problems is that I'm rather inexperienced, so am struggling to understand some of the offerings out there!  Cloudant doesn't look as if it is MySQL based which would mean a significant rewrite of the system which is just unachievable in the timescales.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here are some other alternatives for you, although I agree with Joe Enzminger's AWS RDS answer.

1. ClearDB ([cleardb.com](http://cleardb.com)) - A bit pricey but is probably the most comparable option to    Xeround.
2. RDBHost ([rdbhost.com](http://www.rdbhost.com)) - Although they have been around for some time now I still don't know much about them.
3. Google Cloud SQL ([link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/)) - Ok, its Google but if I remember correctly unless your app is built with Java its pretty difficult to connect outside of Google App Engine.

For more DBAAS offerings you can check out http://www.cloudxl.com/category/database-service/.

Comment: Thanks.  Also looking at cleardb.com, have taken a freebee dB to investigate and working through some of the problems.  Major downside so far that I can see is that it won't allow multiple schema's within the same database instance, so this will ramp cost up.  Also, it won't let me create additional users with different access privilegesto the schema.  Do you know if this is possible

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. I've never actually used cleardb.com. I forgot to mention that if you are using a PaaS like OpenShift, Heroku, or MySQL you might be able to use their service at little or no cost. If you want something a little better use Amazon RDS with reserved instances (you'll save a lot of money).